request for url (https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/): operation timed out
I executed the command solana catchup --our-localhost on the node I built, and it actually returned Error: error sending request for url (https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com/): operation timed out. The node load is not high, and the resources are sufficient, so why can't I request the data?

solana catchup will use two RPC clients: one using the --url specified, which is likely connecting to the public mainnet-beta nodes in your case, and another one against your validator.
The issue appears to be from the connection to the public to the mainnet-beta RPC nodes. It's a bit surprising, but you might need to tweak the number at https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/blob/b1de2e0ce873c7aa2e8470a0a3e3e1ae785ca821/cli/src/cluster_query.rs#L743 by hand and build the CLI yourself, or investigate to find out exactly which RPC call is timing out.
